# Matlab: Saving new instance of object

Tags: matlab, class, object

Say I have the following:

```
classdef Classname
    properties
        property1
    end

    methods
        function a = Classname
        a.property1 = '          ';
        end

        function new = change(a,k)
        a.property1(k) = '!';
        new = a.property1;
        end
    end
end
```

Now when I run this in the console using `a = Classname` and then run the function `change(a,2)` the output I get is: (apostrophes put in for clarity and not part of output)

```
ans = 
' !        '
```

And when I type `ans.property1` I get the same output as above, which is expected, but when I type `a.property1` I just get the original board outputted, which is `'          '`.

My question is, how can I get `a.property1` to display the current saved property1, so it would output `' !        '`

Comment: You might want to make your class a handle class. Because you are using a value class, when you call `change(a,2)` Matlab is probably making a copy of `a` and modifying that copy. Have a look at the [Comparison of Handle and Value Classes](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution via handle class

As Tom pointed out in his comment, you can simply make your `Classname` class a sub-class of the `handle` class:

```
classdef Classname < handle
    properties
        property1
    end

    methods
        function a = Classname
            a.property1 = '          ';
        end

        function new = change(a,k)
            a.property1(k) = '!';
            new = a.property1;
        end
    end
end
```

Now your example provides the desired behaviour:

```
a = Classname;
change(a,2);  % Or a.change(2);
a.property1
```

gives:

```
ans =

 !
```

#### Alternative

If you prefer not to use the handle class, you can re-formulate your `change` method as follows, creating and returning a new instance of your class:

```
classdef Classname
    properties
        property1
    end

    methods
        function a = Classname
            a.property1 = '          ';
        end

        function a_new = change(a,k)
            a_new = a;
            a_new.property1(k) = '!';
        end
    end
end
```

Now the example

```
a = Classname;
a = change(a,2);  % Or a = a.change(2);
a.property1
```

gives:

```
ans =

 !
```